# Search results will not sort by column headers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting

I have a search feature on my site. The results page will give paginated results with whatever the user sets it to, but will not sort the results by column headers.

I can click on them and will get the Desc/Asc arrows, but the page doesn't sort the results accordingly.

Here is the results page:

```
.row-fluid#load_results_table
  .span12
    - if results.empty?
      =render partial: 'no_results', locals: {search: search}
    - else
      %h1.page-header Search Results
      - if results.count > 1000
        %p= "Your search yielded many #{search.search_type.pluralize}"
      - else
        %p= "Your search yielded #{results.count} #{search.search_type.pluralize}"
      =render partial: 'header_buttons', locals: {search: search}
      %br
      %br
      = will_paginate results, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails, id: "first_pagination"
      %table.table.search_results.table-condensed.table-bordered.table-striped.sortable{:id => "#{search.search_type.pluralize}"}
        %thead
          %tr.search_header
            %th= sortable_load "origin"
            %th= sortable_load "dest"
            %th= sortable_load "pickup"
            %th= sortable_load "delivery"
            %th= sortable_load "ltl"
            %th= sortable_load "equipment_id", "Equipment"
            %th= sortable_load "weight"
            %th= sortable_load "length"
            %th= sortable_load "rate"
            -unless @search.origin.blank?
              %th Estimated Deadhead Miles
            %th Actions
        %tbody
          - results.each do |result|
            %tr{:class => "#{search.search_type}_view", :id => "#{result['id']}" }
              %td= Location.to_cs(result.origin)
              %td= Location.to_cs(result.dest)
              %td= format_date(result.pickup)
              %td= format_date(result.delivery)
              %td= full_or_par(result.ltl)
              %td= result.equipment_id ? Equipment.to_equipment_name(result.equipment_id) : ""
              %td= result.weight
              %td= result.length
              %td= result.rate
              -unless @search.origin.blank?
                %td= Location.distance_between(@search.origin.coords, result['origin'])
              %td
                .btn-group
                  %a.btn.btn-info{ :href => "/#{search.search_type.pluralize}/#{result['id']}" } Show
                  %a.btn{ :href => "javascript:void(0)", :class => "save", user_id: @search.user_id, :id => result['id']} Save
                  %a.btn.btn-primary{ :href => "javascript:void(0)", :class => "cover_link", :user_id=> @search.user_id } Cover 
      = will_paginate results, :renderer => BootstrapPagination::Rails
```

Search Model

```
class Search < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :available, :delivery, :dest, :length, :ltl, :origin, :pickup, :rate, :search_type, :user_id, :weight, :expiration, :pickup_operator, :delivery_operator, :expiration_operator, :available_operator, :length_operator, :rate_operator, :weight_operator, :origin_zip, :dest_zip, :origin_radius, :dest_radius, :saved, :date_posted, :order_by, :origin_cs, :results, :dest_cs, :origin_states, :dest_states, :origin_id, :dest_id, :equipment_ids, :temp_origin, :temp_dest, :temp_equipment
  attr_accessor :origin_cs, :dest_cs, :log
  before_validation :convert_cs_to_id

  OPERATORS = ["<=","<",">=",">","=","!="]
  NUMERICALITY_MESSAGE = "Needs to be a number"
  LOCATION_FORMAT_MESSAGE = "Location must be in format (city,ST)"
  LOCATION_PRESENCE_MESSAGE = "Location does not exist"
  validates_inclusion_of :pickup_operator, in: OPERATORS
  validates_inclusion_of :delivery_operator, in: OPERATORS
  validates_inclusion_of :expiration_operator, in: OPERATORS
  validates_inclusion_of :available_operator, in: OPERATORS
  validates_inclusion_of :length_operator, in: OPERATORS
  validates_inclusion_of :rate_operator, in: OPERATORS
  validates_inclusion_of :weight_operator, in: OPERATORS
  validates_inclusion_of :search_type, in: ["load","truck"]
  validates_numericality_of :rate, {allow_nil: true, message: NUMERICALITY_MESSAGE}
  validates_numericality_of :origin_radius,{allow_nil: true, message: NUMERICALITY_MESSAGE}
  validates_numericality_of :dest_radius, {allow_nil: true, message: NUMERICALITY_MESSAGE}
  validates_numericality_of :weight, allow_nil: true, message: NUMERICALITY_MESSAGE
  validates_numericality_of :length, allow_nil: true, message: NUMERICALITY_MESSAGE
  validates_presence_of :search_type
  validates_presence_of :origin_id, :if => :origin_cs?
  validates_presence_of :dest_id, :if => :dest_cs?

  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :equipment
  belongs_to :origin, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: :origin_id
  belongs_to :dest, class_name: "Location", foreign_key: :dest_id



  def search(page)
    where = []
    where << PrepareSearch.states("dest", self.dest_states) unless self.dest_states.blank?
    where << PrepareSearch.states("origin", self.origin_states) unless self.origin_states.blank? 
    where << PrepareSearch.location('origin', self.origin.coords, self.origin_radius) unless self.origin.blank?
    where << PrepareSearch.location('origin', self.origin.coords, self.origin_radius) unless self.origin.blank?
    where << PrepareSearch.zip('origin', self.origin_zip, self.origin_radius) unless self.origin || self.origin_zip.blank?
    where << PrepareSearch.location('dest', self.dest.coords, self.dest_radius) unless self.dest.blank? 
    where << PrepareSearch.zip('dest', self.dest_zip, self.dest_radius) unless self.dest || self.dest_zip.blank?
    where << PrepareSearch.equipment(self.equipment_ids) unless self.equipment_ids.blank?
    where << PrepareSearch.date('created_at', self.date_posted, '>=') unless self.date_posted.blank?
    if self.search_type == 'load'
      select = "loads.id, origin, dest, pickup, delivery, ltl, equipment_id, weight, length, rate"
      where << PrepareSearch.date('pickup', self.pickup, self.pickup_operator) unless self.pickup.blank?
      where << PrepareSearch.date('delivery', self.delivery, self.delivery_operator) unless self.delivery.blank?
      where << PrepareSearch.attribute('length', self.length, self.length_operator) unless self.length.blank?
      where << PrepareSearch.attribute('rate', self.rate, self.rate_operator) unless self.rate.blank?
      where << PrepareSearch.attribute('weight', self.weight, self.weight_operator) unless self.weight.blank?
      where << PrepareSearch.attribute('ltl', self.ltl, '=') unless self.ltl.blank?
    elsif self.search_type == 'truck'
      select = "trucks.id, origin, dest, available, expiration, equipment_id, comments"
      where << PrepareSearch.date('available',self.available,self.available_operator) unless self.available.blank?
      where << PrepareSearch.date('expiration',self.expiration,self.expiration_operator) unless self.expiration.blank?
    end
    where << "covered=false AND deleted=false"
    where = where.join(' AND ')
    order = self.order_by ? self.order_by + " desc" : ""
    limit = "LIMIT=200"
      Module.const_get(self.search_type.capitalize).where(where).select(select).limit(limit).order(order).page(page).per_page(25)
  end

  module PrepareSearch
    def PrepareSearch.equipment(equipments)
      eq = ""
      equipments.each {|e| eq += "'#{e}'," }
      eq = eq[0..-2]
      "equipment_id IN (#{eq})"
    end

    def PrepareSearch.attribute(attribute, value, comparison)
      "#{attribute} #{comparison} #{value}"
    end

    def PrepareSearch.date(type, date, comparison)
      if comparison == '='
        "CAST(#{type} as TEXT) LIKE '%#{date.strftime("%F")}%'"
      elsif comparison == '<='
        "#{type} #{comparison} '#{date.strftime("%F")} 23:59:59'"
      else
        "#{type} #{comparison} '#{date.strftime("%F")}'"
      end
    end

    def PrepareSearch.zip(type, zip, radius)
      location = Location.where(zip: zip).first
      if location
        "(ST_Distance(#{type}, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT( #{location.coords.x} #{location.coords.y} )')) <= #{radius.to_f*1609.334})"
      else
        #if no locations match zip search for location that will never exist.
        "(ST_Distance(#{type}, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT( 1 1 )')) <= #{radius.to_f*1609.334})"
      end
    end

    def PrepareSearch.location(type, location, radius)
      "(ST_Distance(#{type}, ST_GeographyFromText('POINT( #{location.x} #{location.y} )')) <= #{radius.to_f*1609.334})"
    end

    def PrepareSearch.states(type, states)
      states = states.split(",")
      st = ""
      states.each {|s| st += "'#{s}'," }
      st = st[0..-2]
      "#{type}_state IN (#{st})"
    end
  end

  @log = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/searches.log")
  @log.datetime_format = "%F %T"

  private

    def convert_cs_to_id
      temp_origin = Location.where(cs: self.origin_cs.downcase) unless self.origin_cs.blank?
      self.origin_id = temp_origin.blank? ? "" : temp_origin.first.id

      temp_dest = Location.where(cs: self.dest_cs.downcase) unless self.dest_cs.blank?
      self.dest_id = temp_dest.blank? ? "" : temp_dest.first.id
    end

    def origin_cs?
      errors.add(:origin_cs, "not a valid location") if !origin_cs.blank? && origin_id.blank?
      origin_cs.blank? ? false : true
    end

    def dest_cs?
      errors.add(:dest_cs, "not a valid location") if !dest_cs.blank? && dest_id.blank?
      dest_cs.blank? ? false : true
    end
end
```

**UPDATE**

when i click on the Column Headers the Page url changes to

```
http://www.sitename.com/searches/23616?direction=desc&sort=pickup
```

Comment: are you joining tables to create this search? Usually this is what messes with the sorting? Also sorting will not work correctly since you are calling methods inside your table it would be better to include `will_paginate_array` and then return the results using a `select` query. If you post the actual query I or others can probably help since this is where the issue lies.

Comment: Yes have several tables joining

Comment: added the Search model.

Comment: Holy complexity Batman. This might take a while to look through but you might look into a more `rails` like way of creating this query because as of right now I do not see sorting working well for you.

Comment: Very complex. I didn't create this site but I am the one that has to debug all the errors.

Comment: Do you have tests you can run? If I were you I would rip it out and start over.

Comment: I have to agree with @ZachKemp on this one creating a scope with joins would be a better way to go here since I cannot even determine what the models really look like with this it is tough to help. I do not even see some of these headers defined in the select query(i.e.  `weight`, `length`, `rate`, etc. so how can you sort by a column that does not exist?

Comment: Yeah i was really hoping for a quick fix. because the whole site looks like this.

Comment: BTW this was built without test